# Need to create an unnamed constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a notifier provider by using a notifier class. I am getting an error with this code:

```
final eventsNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<EventsNotifier, Events>(() {
  return EventsNotifier();
});
```

The error is **The class 'EventsNotifier' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.**

Here is the EventsNotifier class

```
class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final eventRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('events'));

  @override
  Events build() {
    return Events(   // Return the initial state
      eventName: '',
      eventStartTime: DateTime.now(),
      eventDuration: '',
      eventDate: DateTime.now(),
      eventDescription: '',
      userId: '',
      companyId: '',
    );
  }

  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

 
  void updateEventname(String newEventName) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventName: newEventName);
  }

  void updateeventStartTime(DateTime newEventStartTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventStartTime: newEventStartTime);
  }

  void updateEventDuration(String newEventDuration) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDuration: newEventDuration);
  }

  void updateEventDate(DateTime? newEventDate) {
    state.copyWith(eventDate: newEventDate);
  }

  void updateEventDescription(String newEventDescription) {
    state.copyWith(eventDescription: newEventDescription);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'eventName': eventName,
      'eventStartTime': eventStartTime,
      'eventDuration': eventDuration,
      'eventDate': eventDate,
      'eventDescription': eventDescription,
      'agentId': userId,
      'agencyId': companyId,
    };
  }

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        userId = firestore['agentId'],
        companyId = firestore['agencyId'];
  }
```

I am not sure what an unnamed constructor is or how to add one to the EventsNotifier class.

Can someone please help with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I added this code and the error went away but I don't know if I did the right thing.

```
class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final eventRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('events'));
  EventsNotifier(); <<<<<<< ADDED CODE
```

Comment: yes it's the correct step to resolve the error,it can be useful when creating instances using the `NotifierProvider` or when you need to create an instance of the `EventsNotifier` class without initializing any properties!

Comment: If you have lints, I believe it will complain about build() missing, or not being overridden, or something.